# how can we split a pdf into chapter and sub chapter python

Tags: python-2.7, text-mining

How can I split a big PDF file into chapter and sub chapter. For example my PDF file organizes like this:

- I.Chapter1
- text text
- A.SubChapter1
- texttext
- 1.SubSubChapter1
- texttext
- 2.SubSubChapter1
- texttext
- II.Chapter2
- texttext
- A.SubChapter2
- texttext

I want to get text and write on database as
chaptername chaptertext subchaptername subchaptertext subsubchaptername subsubchaptertext

Thank you for your time and assistance.

.
.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is worked for you, but you can try to read this link:  https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/

Comment: I know this article. I have read this line by line. I couldn't find a solution.